# Why does the fact that $f^{'}(t)$ being continuous insure that $\int_{0}^{T}f^{'}(t)^2 dt$ is finite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Why does the fact that $f^{'}(t)$ being continuous insure that $\int_{0}^{T}f^{'}(t)^2 dt$ is finite

It might be obvious, but I can't see why when we know that that $f^{'}(t)$ is continuous we can conclude that $\int_{0}^{T}f^{'}(t)^2 dt$ is finite.

Any help, reference to some result/course is appreciated thank you

Comment: extreme value theorem

Comment: Why $f^\prime (t)$? Why don't simply use the notation $f(t)$?

Comment: Well any definite integral is finite if it exists, irrespective of the fact whether the integrand is continuous or not. Perhaps you need to clarify your question with more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f'$ is continuous on $[0,T]$ then $(f')^2$ is also continuous there (product of two continuous functions). By Weierstrass' extreme value theorem $(f')^2$ admits then a maximum $M$ and a minimum $m$ on $[0,T]$, i.e. it is bounded. This implies that $$\left| \int_0^T f'(t)^2 \, dt \right| \le \int_0^T |f'(t)|^2 \, dt \le M \cdot T < \infty.$$

Comment: "Weierstrass theorem" is not very helpful since there are at least 5 different "Weierstrass theorem"s. Indeed, what you are referring to is more commonly known as the extreme value theorem (a continuous function on a compact set must attain its supremum and infimum).

Comment: Yes alright, edited.

Answer (score 0):

Because any continuous function on a compact set says $[0,T]$ is bounded,

Therefore for some $m>0$
$$|f'(t) |\le m,~~~\forall t\in [0,T], ~~~$$

thus, $$\int_0^Tf'(t) ^2dt\le Tm^2~$$